# Good Pokemon for the Zero Isle South dungeon?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon-explorers

The Zero Isle dungeons in the Pokemon Mystery Dungeon series (Explorers of Time, Darkness, and Sky specifically) are much more similar to a typical roguelike, adding restrictions that make the dungeon difficult to complete (and forcing you to rely on luck a *little more*). In particular, Zero Isle South makes you enter with no money, no items, and (for the dungeon) resets your Pokemon's level to 1.

However, there are definitely some Pokemon that are better than others for attempting to complete the dungeon. For example, Mew is a great Pokemon because it can learn all TMs you pick up. **What other Pokemon are good for completing Zero Isle South?**

Comment: Also, I just started [a discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/how-should-we-tag-the-pokemon-mystery-dungeon-series) about the tagging of the series over on Meta.

Comment: ...did I just upvote a Pokemon question...? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some of my own research, I found that people seem to suggest these three:

**Smoochum** (it seems almost everybody attempts the dungeon using Smoochum)

- Has the ability **Forewarn**, allowing you to occasionally **evade moves** (even no-miss moves)
- Learns **Sweet Kiss** at level 8, which is a 100 accuracy confusion causing attack
- Learns **Powder Snow** at level 11, giving it a **room-clearing** move

**Aerodactyl**

- Has the **elemental fangs** (Ice, Fire, Thunder) at level 1, giving it a diverse moveset
- Has **Supersonic** at level 1, allowing it to **confuse** enemies

**Spritomb**

- **Amazing stats** at level 1
- Has **Confuse Ray** at level 1, allowing it to **confuse** enemies
- Has **Shadow Sneak** at level 1 (giving it a **ranged** attack)

Comment: I made the answer CW and accepted it to allow other people to add suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using <strike>regi-kick-ass</strike> **Regigigas**, he has great stats at lvl 1 and can have Fire, Ice and Thunder attacks.

At level 1 he has `Ice punch`, `Thunder Punch`, `Mega Punch`, and one more... I wont tell you what though.

At level 3 (I think, I promise he will learn it before lvl 7) he learns `Fire punch`, and he can learn most of the TMs that you'll find.
I got to floor 94 with him.

The only drawback is that he's slow to level up, but he has awesome stats in the beginning!

You could also use **Shedinja**; he has the `Wonder Guard` ability, that means that only super-effective moves can hurt him (he's Bug/Ghost type).

Answer (score 3):

I would either use Rotom or Mew.

I used Rotom for my first trip into this dungeon and got to the 64th floor before fainting. I'd say that's pretty decent for a first try!

Anyways, Rotom's a ghost type so in emergencies you could just go into a wall and attack from there. Also, Rotom knows Confuse Ray right from the start, which helps a lot.

Mew is great for this dungeon because he's got great stats and can learn every TM move, which this dungeon has a lot of. I could easily get to the higher floor levels with this pink destroyer.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think a Magneton would do everyone well.  I got to the 67th floor with him because the Pokemon in the first 20 floors have a bad type matchup with him.  That gives you a whole 20 floors to level up!  But, I only went up to 67.  Try him out and see how he does.

Answer (score 0):

I think Drifblim is the best because it has the unburden ability that makes it deliver moves twice.

Answer (score 0):

I like Articuno, since it learns good moves like Powder Snow and Ice Shard early on. The only problem is that there are quite a few Rock types in the beginning floors.